# jQuery UI Draggable / Sortable 4 column w/ CSS Transitions - Erratic Behavior

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am creating a simple drag and drop layout that incorporates 4 columns with the use of CSS easing effects when positioning. I have tried multiple solutions but nothing solves the problem. Eventually this will be an angularjs app.

Heres the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moonman/evbk6ewe/8/) (this is four columns so spread your browser to view the whole layout)

1. You will notice when you drag a module that sometimes it will let you snap to the grid and show the "placeholder" and some times it won't.
2. Sometimes the ".placeholder" which is the ".marker" in my example will randomly place the .marker div above the containing li elements causing this to happen.

[Link to marker image](http://www.nathanstaton.com/sandbox/img/marker.png)

Is there a way to force the element to always be on the bottom element of all the li items of a parent ul?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var stylesheet = $('style[name=impostor_size]')[0].sheet;
var rule = stylesheet.rules ? stylesheet.rules[0].style : stylesheet.cssRules[0].style;
var setPadding = function(atHeight) {
    rule.cssText = 'border-top-width: '+atHeight+'px'; 
};

$('.button-up').click(function(){
    updateWidgetData();
});

$('.main-area ul').sortable({
    connectWith: '.column',
    cursor: 'move',
    placeholder: 'marker',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    opacity: 0.4,
    start: function(event, ui){
        setPadding(ui.item.height());
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        ui.item.css({'top':'0','left':'0'}); //Opera fix
        if(!$.browser.mozilla && !$.browser.safari)
            updateWidgetData();
        var next = ui.item.next();
        next.css({'-moz-transition':'none', '-webkit-transition':'none', 'transition':'none'});
        setTimeout(next.css.bind(next, {'-moz-transition':'border-top-width 0.1s ease-in', '-webkit-transition':'border-top-width 0.1s ease-in', 'transition':'border-top-width 0.1s ease-in'}));
    }
}).disableSelection();


function updateWidgetData() {
    var items = [];
    $('.column').each(function() {
        var columnId=$(this).attr('id');
        $('.dragbox', this).each(function(i) {
            var item = {
                id: $(this).attr('id'),
                order : i,
                column: columnId
            };
            items.push(item);
        });
    });
    var sortorder = { items: items };
    //Pass sortorder variable to server using ajax to save state
    $.post('updatePanels.php', 'data='+$.toJSON(sortorder), function(response) {
        if(response=="success")
            $("#console").html('<div class="success">Saved</div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#console').fadeOut(1000);
        }, 2000);

    });
}
```